# CKeditor doesn't work with content rendered with renderAjax()

Tags: ckeditor, yii2

I installed CKeditor for Yii2 according to [extension docs](https://github.com/2amigos/yii2-ckeditor-widget/blob/master/README.md).

I have pages in rendered in controller for eg.:

```
public function actionTest($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);

    return $this->renderAjax('/test', ['model' => $model]);
}
```

CKeditor loads properly if it is via:

```
return $this->render('/test', ['model' => $model]);
```

but does not load if it is loaded via `renderAjax()`. Seems to be CKeditor's jquery missing in this content. May I know how to add it to this page?

In my view:

```
    <?= $form->field($model, 'Desc')->label('Description'. Html::tag('span', '*',['class'=>'required']))->widget(CKEditor::className(), [
            'options' => ['rows' => 6],
            'preset' => 'basic'
        ]) 
    ?>
```

Comment: What are the textreas that CKEditor attached to?

Comment: Hi arogachev its like the previous question which u helped me with. My ckeditor loads in the form for the modal loaded via Create New button but does not load when its loaded via the update button inside gridview which loads renderAjax page modal. I have no access to my codes now i will update u with more info when i get hold of access. Thks!

Answer (score 1):

In case of dynamically loaded textarea you need to reinitialize CKEditor in AJAX success callback.

It can be done like so:

```
CKEDITOR.replace('id-of-your-textarea-field');
```

Links:

- [Cannot convert dynamically loaded teaxtarea into ckeditor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19988754/cannot-convert-dynamically-loaded-teaxtarea-into-ckeditor)
- [Official docs](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR-method-inline)

Comment: something is strange. When i click on update in the gridview, modal loads with ckeditor. Then i click on create new button above gridview and modal loads with ckeditor. However now i click back to update inside gridview, ckeditor will not load anymore. Can you help me please?

Comment: Heres my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28575358/yii2-ckeditor-loading-in-modal-conflicts-when-there-is-more-than-once-instance-o